# Why does an angular factory interfere with MongoId?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, mongoid, capybara

I do have a Rails application (Rails 4 / Mongoid) which uses Capybara / Rspec. Furthermore I do use Angular.js for some client stuff. Unfortunately I experience a strange behavior in a spec test.

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Offer
```

`creating_offers_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'creating offers' do
    before do
        visit '/offers/new'
    end

    scenario 'can create an offer', js: true do
        offer_number = Random.rand(10000)

        fill_in 'offer_number', with: offer_number
        fill_in 'offer_description', with: 'hello world!'

        click_button 'btn_submit'

        offer_in_db = Offer.where(number: offer_number).first
        expect(offer_in_db.description).to eql 'hello world!'
    end
end
```

As JavaScript driver for Capybara I do use poltergeist.

`OfferController.js.coffee`

```
angular.module('exampleApp').controller 'OffersController', ($scope, Offer) ->
    $scope.offer = {}
    $scope.offer.positions = []

    $scope.addOffer = ->
        new Offer().create($scope.offer)

    $scope.addPosition = ->
        position = { order: $scope.offer.positions.length + 1 }
        $scope.offer.positions.push(position)
```

`OfferService.js.coffee`

```
angular.module('exampleApp').factory 'Offer', ($resource, $http) ->
    class Offer
        constructor: ->
            @service = $resource('/api/offers/:offersId', {offersId: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PATCH'}})

            defaults = $http.defaults.headers
            defaults.patch = defaults.patch || {}
            defaults.patch['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

        create: (attrs) ->
            offer = new @service(offer: attrs)
            offer.$save ($offer) ->
                attrs.id = $offer._id
            attrs
```

Now when I rename the service to OfferService, I don't get the error with the circular dependency. Why does the angular.js service interfere with the mongoid model?

Update: I just figured out that the circular dependency issue does also raise even when I do rename the controller. I forgot to uncomment the `Offer.where(...)` part of the spec. Why does this happen or let me ask otherwise, any ideas what I could have messed up?

### Update I

I've added the `gem 'capybara-angular'` and included it into the `spec_helber.rb` as described on https://github.com/wrozka/capybara-angular. At least the test do run know. Unfortunately I experience now the problem, that the evaluate_script gets no longer routed to poltergeist because of the above gem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get circular dependency issues I usually tag my scenario with @allow-rescue

I still try to do some negative testing to make sure that once I have that tag, it still asserts the proper things and errors if I check for incorrect things.